# October CMS Blog Embed Audio does not enable for writers

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have two blog writers as other users for the October CMS site I have, and he and she are able to embed audio using the audio embed in the editor, however it does not appear when the post is published.

Only when I as super admin go in and resave the blog entry does it show up in the website.

Is there a setting that was missed to enable other blog writers to save media embeds as posts are published?

Answer (score 1):

The role needs the **"Upload and manage media contents - images, videos, sounds, documents"** permission.

[image: Permission config]

Comment: Thanks. That is enabled actually.
Have already figured out the issue from the same question asked in the Github repository.
It is a markdown permission. Since it might be a security issue, it is not mentioned here the permission setting.